Book about crashing onto an alien planet
I read a book roughly 10 years ago, it was about a boy (?) crashing his spaceship onto an alien planet. I can’t remember much but it was a book for kids/young adults as I was about 10 years old when I read it.
I can’t remember if he encountered aliens, but I do remember the word plateau was mentioned a lot, along with fronds, he had to eat them and use them to collect water to survive.

Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember the cover at all?  Were there illustrations?

Very vaguely, I think it was a dark cover? With some red on it possibly. No illustrations in the book. Thanks!

Your summary reminds me of James Blish's Welcome To Mars! A boy travels to Mars via his discovery of anti-gravity and is sustained by oxygen- capturing lichen or something similar.

The word "plateau" only appears twice and the word "frond" not at all, although the word lichen appears a dozen times or more.

I don’t think it’s this, I think it was published a lot more recently (probably late 90s-2000s) but thank you!
